# Is it possible to install just the mongo Shell?

Tags: mongodb, mac-os-x

I have Docker installed and am running a `MongoDB` container for my local development on my Mac.  The problem is that I can't connect to said DB easily from CLI.  I have [Robo 3T](https://robomongo.org/) installed, but I would prefer to use the `CLI` client instead.

Is there a known way to install JUST the `mongo shell` (command `mongo`) and not the full DB distribution on OS X?

Comment: I don't think because "The mongo shell is an interactive JavaScript interface to MongoDB".

Comment: Look at [Install ONLY mongo shell, not mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42001338/install-only-mongo-shell-not-mongodb)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use HomeBrew, see the official [MongoDB HomeBrew](https://github.com/mongodb/homebrew-brew) page.

Just add the tap:

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
```

And then after adding the tap from above, you can then install the Mongo shell with:

```
brew install mongodb-community-shell
```

Comment: `brew install mongosh`.  The "mongo" shell has been superseded by "mongosh" (c)

Answer (score 11):

You can download the latest Mongo Shell for MacOS from the following URL:

https://downloads.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-shell-osx-ssl-x86_64-3.6.2.tgz

For the sake of completion, the Mongo Shell for Windows is available at https://downloads.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.6.2-signed.msi

Furthermore, for other Linux distributions, I suggest you create a MongoDB Atlas cluster (for instance, a free M0 cluster) at www.mongodb.com/atlas where you'll find the Mongo Shell downloads for all OSes in the Connect dialog of your cluster.

I hope this helps.

Comment: O.P operating systems environment is Mac-os-x. How he will install 'mongo shell' in that environment. And how will be set the default port 27017 there.

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan The MacOS tarball (tgz) link in this answer is the minimal download asked for in the question: a ~10MB download which only includes the `mongo` 3.6.2 shell binary and the accompanying license notices. There really isn't an install step aside from unpacking the tgz file (double-click to open) and running `bin/mongo` to connect to an existing MongoDB deployment with appropriate connection parameters. An alternative would be to download the full MacOS distribution (~90MB) and only run the `bin/mongo` command. That would leave other tools like `mongodump` available if needed.

Comment: Thanks Rahael. Very useful answer. Just what I was looking for.

Comment: @Md Haidar Ali Khan no need to set the port, 27017 is the default. You only need to set  it if the server is different.

Comment: newer version: https://fastdl.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-shell-macos-x86_64-4.2.2.tgz

Answer (score 1):

I understand you have mongo running on Docker, so as a workaround you can use the same running container to connect:

```
docker exec -ti $container_name bash
bash-4.2$ mongo -u $MONGODB_USER -p $MONGODB_PASSWORD $MONGODB_DATABASE
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.6.3
```

Ideally you could connect with just one command but I don't know why is failing when calling from outside:

```
# this fail but you can use with other databases
docker exec -ti $container_name mongo -u $MONGODB_USER -p $MONGODB_PASSWORD $MONGODB_DATABASE
```

The idea is simple, mongo is installed on the container so you tell docker to run from inside the container. If you need to load files from outside you always can mount a volume.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. why install tools when it is already there inside container

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so in **macOS** whitout installation of MongoDB ,you can able to connect `mongo shell`.
To install `MongoDB Community Edition` on **macOS** system [Install MongoDB Community Edition on macOS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/) You may download [MongoDB Community Edition](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?_ga=2.185913196.474974308.1517120234-1505414474.1511857758#atlas) through either the MongoDB Download Center or the popular macOS package manager [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

As [The mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/) is an interactive JavaScript interface to MongoDB.

> **Note:** Ensure that `MongoDB` is running before attempting to start the `mongo` shell.

For your further ref [Here](https://treehouse.github.io/installation-guides/mac/mongo-mac.html) and [Here](https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/how-to-install-mongodb-on-mac-os-x/)